# Spring cron expression list of nth day of week

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want a task to be run every first monday and wednesday of the month. To do that I wanted to use the following cron expression : 0 0 1 ? * MON#1,WED#1 but it only runs on first monday and not on first wednesday. I have tested my expression on the following link http://www.cronmaker.com/ but it only confirms what I see and I do not find a solution. Can anybody help please ?
Thanks

Comment: Well, I think that I must create two entries to do that : one dedicated for mondays and one for wednesdays.

Comment: yeah ... also this should be duplicate in favor of a more generic question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438621/multiple-nth-weekday-of-month-in-a-single-quartz-cron-expression