# Multiple 'nth' weekday of month in a single quartz cron expression

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm trying to write a cron expression for quartz that runs hourly everyday except every second Saturday of the month.

So, by using the '#' notation, I was trying to write the expression like:

`0 0 * ? * SUN-FRI,SAT#1,SAT#3,SAT#4,SAT#5`

This expression is not working properly. Also, quartz is not complaining about the cron format (quartz usually complains about cron expressions when they are wrong).

So I did some other experiments today. So, today is the third Thursday of the month, I was playing around with THU#N notation, and that's what I've found so far (I changed my expression to minute to make it easier for experimenting):

`0 * * ? * SUN-FRI,SAT#1,SAT#3,SAT#4,SAT#5`: not triggered
`0 * * ? * THU#3`: triggered
`0 * * ? * THU#3,THU#4`: not triggered
`0 * * ? * THU#2,THU#3`: triggered

I know I can simply split this into 4 additional expression but in my real scenario I have tons of expressions to change and this would increase my expression list to something 5 times longer.

In a brief: Does anyone knows how to condense these:

`0 0 * ? * SUN-FRI` / `0 0 * ? * SAT#1` / `0 0 * ? * SAT#3` / `0 0 * ? * SAT#4` / `0 0 * ? * SAT#5`

...into a single cron expression?

Note: I'm using quartz scheduler 1.5 (I know, I know... pretty outdated)

Comment: I tried to find out whether your issue was resolved with releases following 1.5. I did not find out, but instead, I stumbled across Quartz' bug tracker search page - I will search it later for a similar issue, maybe you beat me to it:
https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa

Comment: Mh. Maybe this one? https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-66

Comment: Hopefully they will work on the final solution for this instead of just doing what I saw in the comment "In the mean time I've added code that will fail-fast if such an expression is attempted"

Comment: Sounds like this was fixed on 2.1.2:
https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-255?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel